# "Can't find symbol" error in the java.math.BigInteger class

Tags: java

I'm trying to write code for a function that inputs String and returns its remainder when divided by 7 as an 'int'.
For some reason I'm getting the following error,

```
    Main.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        n=java.math.BigInteger.bg.intValue();
                          ^
    symbol:   variable bg
    location: class BigInteger
    1 error
```

My code is as follows,

```
    /* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

    import java.util.*;
    import java.lang.*;
    import java.io.*;

    /* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
    class Ideone
    {
        int remainderWith7(String num)
        {
            // Your code here
            java.math.BigInteger bg=new java.math.BigInteger(num);
            Integer n=java.math.bg.intValue();
            //int n=java.util.Integer.parseInt(num);
            //hello
            return (int)n%7;
        }
        public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
        {
            // your code goes here
            Ideone id=new Ideone();
            id.remainderWith7("10");
        }
    }
```

Please help.
Thank You.

Comment: `bg` is just the name of your variable. Why are you trying to qualify it with `java.math`? Just use `Integer n = bg.intValue();` (Also note that the code you've given doesn't match the error message you've shown - it's always worth making sure you're consistent.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank You. That totally worked.

Answer (score 3):

There is no attributes in math that's named `bg`.

Change the line to:

```
Integer n= bg.intValue();
```

Comment: Could you also tell that when inputting something as "56495654565052555054535456545355495650575755555757575350505449495254525056535655494951545354515152515050575749545453535549545551575652535149494949515551545554565555575452555157505555574950505649525149505150575254515549565156515750555450545355495355515251495352565452555453515451505251575251494956515352555154505155535151565754505450535753555654575549575349565351575054", the output is coming out to be 0, while the desired output is 6 ?!?

Comment: Check the result of bg.intValue() it's probably a multiple of 7. You can't use a BigInteger and convert it to Integer without loosing digits.

Comment: Computing the code with the above String as input is throwing a runtime error as follows, `Runtime error time: 0.04 memory: 711168 signal:-1`

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BigIntergerSumExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        BigInteger number1;
        BigInteger number2;
        BigInteger sum;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the value of number 1");
        number1 = sc.nextBigInteger();
        System.out.println("Enter the value of number 2");
        number2 = sc.nextBigInteger();


        BigInteger a = new BigInteger(""+number1);
        BigInteger b = new BigInteger(""+number2);
        BigInteger result = a.add(b);

        System.out.println("Sum is Two numbers : -> " + result);
    }

}


Answer is

Enter the value of number 1
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
Enter the value of number 2
2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
Sum is Two numbers : -> 
3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
```

Comment: import java.math.BigInteger;